# Getting confused with useSelector

Tags: react-native, react-redux

So i wanted to get access to state (using redux for state management) using `connect` function from `react-redux`.

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```

But when i tried to access the state values, it returned undefined.

Then, the only change which i did was to remove `connect` and introduce my component with the `useSelector` hook and it worked fine.

Till now, i was thinking that they are same (in terms of providing access to the state), but it worked totally different.

Here is the code(which i think is of no use in the context of this question, but maybe i am wrong);

Using `useSelector`

```
const UnRegisteredStack = (props) => {
    const { token, verified } = useSelector((state) => ({
        token: state.token,
        verified: state.verified,
    }));
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            {token == null ? (
                <unRegistered.Navigator
                    initialRouteName="login"
                    screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
                >
                    <unRegistered.Screen name="login" component={Login} />
                    <unRegistered.Screen name="register" component={Register} />
                    <unRegistered.Screen name="passwordreset" component={PasswordReset} />
                </unRegistered.Navigator>
            ) : (
                <unRegistered.Navigator
                    initialRouteName="verifyemail"
                    screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
                >
                    {verified == null ? (
                        <unRegistered.Screen name="verifyemail" component={VerifyEmail} />
                    ) : (
                        <unRegistered.Screen name="details" component={Details} />
                    )}
                </unRegistered.Navigator>
            )}
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
```

Using `connect`

```
const UnRegisteredStack = (props) => {
    const { token, verified } = props;
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            {token == null ? (
                <unRegistered.Navigator
                    initialRouteName="login"
                    screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
                >
                    <unRegistered.Screen name="login" component={Login} />
                    <unRegistered.Screen name="register" component={Register} />
                    <unRegistered.Screen name="passwordreset" component={PasswordReset} />
                </unRegistered.Navigator>
            ) : (
                <unRegistered.Navigator
                    initialRouteName="verifyemail"
                    screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
                >
                    {verified == null ? (
                        <unRegistered.Screen name="verifyemail" component={VerifyEmail} />
                    ) : (
                        <unRegistered.Screen name="details" component={Details} />
                    )}
                </unRegistered.Navigator>
            )}
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   token: state.token,
   verified: state.verified

})

connect(mapStateToProps)(UnRegisteredStack)
```

Comment: Why does `mapState`  access `state.token` while the `useSelector`  access `state.authReducer.token` ?

Comment: Sorry that is just typo. Will edit it

Comment: Ok I will assume the issue is that you are exporting and using `UnRegisteredStack` in both cases but when using `connect` you need to export and use what is returned from the connect function. e.g. `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UnRegisteredStack)` so that is what is imported by default. This is just speculation from me though since it's not clear how you're using this in each case

Comment: @apokryfos thanks. I think i got it. As i was using the older component but i need to use the connected one.

Comment: @apokryfos please add this comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference that is omitted from the documentation is that a component that uses `useSelector` uses the newer React philosophy of hooks and can then be used itself without needing a separate wrapper component while `connect(...)(UnRegisteredStack)` is using the older philosophy of agumenting a component by wrapping it in a wrapper so e.g.:

```
const UnRegisteredStackHooks = (props) => {
    const { token, verified } = useSelector((state) => ({
        token: state.token,
        verified: state.verified,
    }));
    // rest of component
}

const UnRegisteredStackUnconnected = (props) => {
    // rest of component
}
const UnRegisteredStackConnected = connect(mapStateToProps)(UnRegisteredStackUnconnected);

const App = () => (
   <Provider store={store}>
      {/* Works ok */}
      <UnRegisteredStackHooks /> 
      {/* Needs the props passed */}
      <UnRegisteredStackUnconnected token={store.getState().token} />
      {/* Works ok */}
      <UnRegisteredStackConnected />
   </Provider>

);
```

There's advantages and disadvantages to both approaches. With `connect` you retain the option of having a component that will work without being coupled with redux since you can always export the component without `connect` and introduce connect elsewhere. This is particularly useful when testing if you don't want to create a mock store.

On the other hand hooks make it a lot simpler to define the component and you can always just mock the hooks if you need to test.

Comment: My only problem was, i forgot to use the connected component as was using the component directly. Thanks.